# Database Design Performance of Many Table vs One Table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

Say I have an ANIMAL table,

```
CREATE TYPE VALID_ANIMAL AS ENUM ('Dog', 'Cat', 'Pig');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ANIMAL (
  animal_type VALID_ANIMAL,
  name        TEXT,
  owner       TEXT,
  .... many more common fields
);
```

So if this table is very large 1 millions row with mixture of "Dog", "Cat" and "Pig" will it slow down the search for row containing "Dog"?

Or should I have 3 separate tables named DOG, CAT and PIG. This way the data is already separated and when querying for DOG I will just go to dog table. I am worried that one large table might have performance issue in term of filtering out "Cat" and "Pig" while searching for "Dog".

Comment: This is not how you should do database design.  You don't worry about row counts during relational data design.

Comment: I am just curious on which approach will be faster so I can implement in the application : )

Comment: It is faster to get the data design right first, then you will have many more viable options for performance tuning afterward.

Comment: @RBarryYoung hi so according to design view, one table is good design?

Comment: I guess this depends on what query you are firing, If you are firing query for dogs, cats and other animals together then one table is better for one reason that your query doesn't need to have joins but if you are querying the data separately for animals then different tables make sense

Comment: If they all have the same columns and the same relationships to other tables, then they probably should all be in one table.  But we cannot say for sure because you haven't given us any of the information that we normally have when doing a relational data design.  I'd recommend that you find a good tutorial online for relational data design (there are many) and walk through that first.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1,000,000 rows then you probably have about 300,000 rows for each animal.  You really cannot speed up a query that fetches one in three rows.

That is not strictly true.  There are two things you can do.  You can partition by the tables by animal type.  A million row table is on the low end for partitioning.

The other thing is that you can create a clustered index on the animal type.  In MySQL, you would do this by declaring a composite primary key with animal type as the first specified key.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you explain more on "You really cannot speed up a query that fetches one in three rows."

Which will be faster querying big table for "Dog" with name of "Foo" (lets say I'll get 5000 dogs)

vs

querying Dog table with name of "Foo"

Comment: @Zanko . . . With an index on `name`, the speed would be essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you so much!